# DoNotForward Graph Api Event With Java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application I am working on where a user will make an reservation for an office. Once the user makes it they are sent a calendar event via graph api so their Calendar reflects their reservation. I am trying to use the DoNotForward Boolean type to send in the singleValueExtendedProperties setting but nothing has worked.

Please Only answer using Java as the language. Thank you

**Note that I am sending the event and receiving it without any trouble until I try to add the DoNotForward. Below is a portion of the code that represents the Graph API Event.

Questions:
Has anyone configured an Event with the DoNoForward Option?
Can you provide me some guidance on what I am doing wrong?

```
Event event = new Event();
        
        ItemBody eventBody = new ItemBody();
        eventBody.contentType = BodyType.HTML;
        eventBody.content = doc.html();
        event.body = eventBody;
        event.subject = "MyWorkSpot Reservation (" + environmentName + ") : "  + buildingName + " Floor: " + floorName + " Seat: " + seatCode + " Time: " + reservationTime;

        event.showAs = FreeBusyStatus.FREE;
        event.isReminderOn = false;
        event.reminderMinutesBeforeStart = 0;
        event.isAllDay = true;
        
        DateTimeTimeZone start = new DateTimeTimeZone();
        start.dateTime = formattedResAllDayStartDate + "T00:00:00";
        start.timeZone = "Eastern Standard Time";
        event.start = start;
        DateTimeTimeZone end = new DateTimeTimeZone();
        end.dateTime = nextDay + "T00:00:00";
        end.timeZone = "Eastern Standard Time";
        event.end = end;   

        LinkedList<Attendee> attendeesList = new LinkedList<Attendee>();
        Attendee attendees = new Attendee();
        EmailAddress emailAddressEvent = new EmailAddress();
        emailAddressEvent.address = recipientEmailAddress;
        attendees.emailAddress = emailAddressEvent;
        attendees.type = AttendeeType.REQUIRED;
        attendeesList.add(attendees);
        event.attendees = attendeesList;

        SingleValueLegacyExtendedPropertyCollectionResponse singleValColRes = new SingleValueLegacyExtendedPropertyCollectionResponse();

        SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty singleValProp = new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty();
        singleValProp.id = "Boolean {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name DoNotForward";
        singleValProp.value = "true";
        singleValProp.oDataType = "Boolean";
        singleValColRes.value.add(0, singleValProp);
    
        event.singleValueExtendedProperties = new SingleValueLegacyExtendedPropertyCollectionPage(singleValColRes, null);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please, the question is too broad, unclear and needs some code. Please, provide specific questions in order we can help you.

Comment: What does this have to do with `facebook-graph-api`?

Comment: I have to change that. I typed graph-api and didnt notice that it auto filled to facebook-graph-api. Thank you